# Spring Boot Cache + Apache ignite + Spring Boot Actuator - Application fail to start when running tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, testng, ignite, spring-boot-actuator

I have a project where i use Spring Boot 2.0.0+ , Spring Boot Cache, Apache Ignite, Spring Boot Actuator and TestNG.

Since I've upgraded from ignite 2.5 to ignite 2.6+, I've been facing issues while trying to run Application tests, because every time the application starts on the test Task, ignite fails to register it's cache metrics on the `CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration`.

The application fails with the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AssertionError
```

I've create an application that showcases this issue, you can access it through this link:

https://github.com/pmrochaubi/apache-ignite-spring-boot-actuator

Can someone explain me what's happening and how I can solve this? Currently I'm stuck on version 2.5...

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say who is exactly to blame here, but as you can see:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.spring.SpringCacheManager.getCacheNames(SpringCacheManager.java:371) ~[ignite-spring-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration.bindCacheManagerToRegistry(CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration.java:73) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration.bindCachesToRegistry(CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration.java:69) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
```

`SpringCacheManager.getCacheNames()` is called from `postProcessBeforeInitialization()`. However it should be pretty obvious that you can only get cache names after cache initialization, e.g., after Ignite is up and `onApplicationEvent()` is called on `SpringCacheManager`.

This is an interesting question for actuator's `CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration` why they feel the need to call this method in `@PostConstruct` method when nothing is started yet.

Comment: do you have any ideia how can i solve it? I can disable the cachemanager in tests, but i don't like this solution.

Comment: You could call `onApplicationEvent()` on `SpringCacheManager` before returning it.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how can i implement this ?

Comment: `cacheManager.onApplicationEvent(null);` before doing `return;`

Comment: but the method `onApplicationEvent` doesn't exist

Comment: I can definitely see it on `SpringCacheManager`.

Comment: Sorry i was looking in version 2.5, you are right the method exists in version 2.7. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution that worked for me is to add it to main class, With this Autoconfiguration will be disabled for Metrics, you have to make your own configuration as needed.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {CacheMetricsAutoConfiguration.class})
```